# Eye pops out of its socket while the other one does not

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]
Hi, I'm quite new to rigging and this model and rig from Pixel Urge have some weird issue. Right eye is fine while left eye pops out of its socket when I start to animate it. I've already been searching for a fix for this for hours, I've even asked help from other blender users, but they don't know how to fix it. Here's the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KD6R4EhTBPK4v2GASOWfkAsvWYizFH67/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2 eye objects share the same mesh, therefore they share the same vertex group (*c_eye.r*) and are controlled by the same bone. What you need to do is separate the 2 meshes by clicking on the *Make Single User* button in the *Object Data* panel:

[image]

Then change the name of the vertex group for the left eye to *c_eye.l* so that it will be controlled by the bone that has the same name:

[image]